# What's the cross-sectional area of a grating?

Tags: cross-sections

This is related to the electrical concept of resistance, but in the equation of resistance

$$R = \frac{ρ l}{A}$$

there's the cross-sectional area $A$ of the conductor.

Now if the conductor is a grating

[image]

then what's the cross-sectional area of such "flat" object? Is it the area of the object itself?

Answer (score 1):

This is the second Ohm's law.

It's related to electric wires.

$A$ would be the section of the wire, which is usually the area of a circumference.

I believe your question is meaningless since you're understanding $A$ as the normal area of a geometric shape.

That law is related to electric wires.

Comment: What's the area of a circumference? Isn't circumference only a property of circles?

Comment: @mavavilj Sorry, in Italian we indicate "circumference" as a synonym of "circle" and I forgot that it's technically the name of the area of the circle instead :D